# How to create and parse Tag, Length, Value (TLV) in .Net and encode it in Base64

Tags: .net, vb.net, qr-code, invoice, tlv

The QR code fields shall be encoded in Tag-Length-Value (TLV) format with the tag values specified in the “Tag” column of the adjacent table.

The TLV encoding shall be as follows:

Tag: the tag value as mentioned above stored in one byte.
Length: the length of the byte array resulted from the UTF8 encoding of the field value. The length shall be stored in one byte.
Value: the byte array resulting from the UTF8 encoding of the field value.

**Looking for Asp.net/Vb.net**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried? Add the code to your question, pointing our where it goes wrong. Error message? etc. Take the [tour].

Comment: I don't know where to start, I found some posts about the same but it was in PHP by @Salla ( https://github.com/SallaApp/ZATCA ), looking similar library for vb.net

Comment: Most libraries made for .Net are usable in vb.net. Google "TLV in .net". I got many results.

Comment: Yes i did it, found 2, one for PHP and other one for JAVA. Actually this is related to ZATCA, New e-Invoicing Project in KSA. Still googling and posted here if someone else found something.

Comment: Questions that seek software libraries are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Refer to this post, the same i am looking but in .Net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530804/how-to-create-and-parse-tag-length-value-tlv-in-php-and-encode-it-in-base64

Comment: Have you tried to search the word `ZATCA` in GitHub?

Comment: I tired, found your code for PHP

Comment: https://github.com/aljbri/Zatca.Net & https://github.com/alquhait/ZatcaDotNetCore & https://github.com/GeeSuth/GeeSuthSoft.KSA.ZATCA

Answer (score 3):

I was able to successfully create the TLV encoding in vb.net and it passed Zatca validation.
I created a very simple form with 5 inputs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUQFk.png)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim value1 As String = getTLV(1, TextBox1.Text)
        Dim value2 As String = getTLV(2, TextBox2.Text)
        Dim value3 As String = getTLV(3, TextBox3.Text)
        Dim value4 As String = getTLV(4, TextBox4.Text)
        Dim value5 As String = getTLV(5, TextBox5.Text)
        Dim b As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value1 & value2 & value3 & value4 & value5)
        Dim t As String = Convert.ToBase64String(b)
        TextBox6.Text = t
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function getTLV(tag As Integer, value As String) As String
    Return Chr(tag) & Chr(value.Length) & value
End Function
```